# Locking around JavaScript async method

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, locking

I have an async method, `run`, that accepts tasks but shouldn't be called concurrently since it spawns a separate resource intensive process for each task.

To do this I have tried to implement a proxy function, `queue` that is called by another module whenever there are new tasks to run. This function should allow *at most* one piece of asynchronous code inside the `run` function at any time. I.e. each task should acquire a lock that is not released until processing is finished.

My approach so far:

```
let promise;

const queue = (...args) => {
    promise = (async() => {
        try {
            await promise;
        } catch (e) {
            // returned promised is consumed elsewhere hence empty catch block
        }
        return run(...args);
    })();
    return promise;
};

const run = async (task) => {
    console.log('Running ' + task);
    // some resource intensive process is started
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
    });
};

// calling module without error handling
(async() => {
    await Promise.all([1, 2, 3].map(queue));
    console.log('All tasks finished');
})();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't let me see when the queue is empty or how many tasks are currently waiting in the queue.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is pretty good, and perhaps you could just set up some queue counter to track the current task and tasks left in the queue. I do think this could perhaps be a bit simplified if you ignore `Promise.all` and `map` entirely, perhaps with something like this:

```
// custom Promise method that takes an array of tasks 
// and the function to run said tasks individually

Promise.each = async function(tasks, fn) {
  for (const task of tasks) {
    // you can track progress in here by updating some counter,
    // or calling some update function
    await fn(task);
  }
  console.log('All tasks finished');
};

const run = (task) => {
    console.log('Running ' + task);
    // some resource intensive process is started
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          asyncLock = false;
          resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
};

Promise.each([1, 2 ,3], run);
```